# How to modify this equation in order to find $x$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

This comes from physics environment. Would anyone be able to help me alternate this equation in order to find the $x$?

I need to have this equation in the form of $x = 
 \text{...something}$.
$$ A = \frac{B}{C} - \Bigg( \frac{B}{C} - \frac{B}{D} \Bigg)e^{- \frac{BF}{X}} $$
Please note: $e$ is an Euler's number here, and this is $e$ to the power of minus $\frac{BF}{X}$ (looks little bit confusing).

My attempt:

$- \frac{A - \frac{B}{C}}{\frac{B}{C} - \frac{B}{D}} = e^{-\frac{BF}{X}}$

$\frac{D(AC-B)}{B(C-D)} = e^{-\frac{BF}{X}}$

$\ln{\Bigg(\frac{D(AC-B)}{B(C-D)}\Bigg)} = -\frac{BF}{X}$

$1 = -\frac{BF}{X\ln{\Bigg(\frac{D(AC-B)}{B(C-D)}\Bigg)}}$

$X = -\frac{BF}{\ln{\Bigg(\frac{D(AC-B)}{B(C-D)}\Bigg)}}$

However I'm not sure if it's correct.

Help's appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to reorganize the terms isolating the exponential in one side of the equation and the rest on the other side?

Comment: I've edited my post with my attempted solution.

Comment: I think you "lost" a minus sign between the 1st and the 2nd line of your computations.

Comment: Not really my computation, that part was done by wolfram.

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=simplify+-(a-b%2Fc)%2F(b%2Fc+-+b%2Fd)
I hope it's correct.

Comment: My mistake, sorry. You solution seems correct to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the problem of

$$A=G-He^{-\frac{K}{X}}$$

We have

$$He^{-\frac{K}{X}}=G-A$$

$$e^{-\frac{K}{X}}=\frac{G-A}{H}$$

Hence

$$-\frac{K}{X}=\log\left(\frac{G-A}{H} \right)$$

Hopefully you can continue from here.

Edit:

$$\frac{K}{X}=\log\left( \frac{H}{G-A}\right)$$

Hence

$$X=\frac{K}{\log\left( \frac{H}{G-A}\right)}$$

Now, $K=BF,  G=\frac{B}{C}, H=\frac{B}{C}-\frac{B}{D}$

Hence,

$$X=\frac{BF}{\log\left( \frac{\frac{B}{C}-\frac{B}{D}}{\frac{B}{C}-A}\right)}=\frac{BF}{\log\left( \frac{\frac{BD-BC}{CD}}{\frac{B-AC}{C}}\right)}=\frac{BF}{\log\left( \frac{B(D-C)}{D(B-AC)}\right)}$$

Comment: Hey, I edited my post with my solution. Would you be able to verify, please? Thanks.

Comment: our answers agree.